# What is this "tool" and how is it used?

Tags: soldering, soldering-iron-station, rework

I purchased a rework station, and it came with the tool shown. I've never seen or used such a device before but checking the illustration of a couple of other rework stations showed similar tools supplied with rework stations. However, the contents listings mostly omit it, as far as I can see; one did list "disassemble tool", but I'd have thought tweezers were a better choice for lifting desoldered components.

The plastic handle is 9cm (3.5 inches) long. The metal 'arms' are about 5cm (2 inches) and the tips are 3cm (1.25 inches) apart.

What is it and what's it used for?

[image: My device]

These are pictures of a couple of images of similar ones.

[image: Curved arms]
[image: Straight arms]

Comment: It is an "IC popper" to lift IC from PCB/socket. This is a duplicate of a recent question, need to find it..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. Once I have the name, I found dozens of images on the web! I still think a pair of fine tipped tweezers would give better control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a little prybar that you can get under surface mount legs and flip the chip off the pad.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll carry on using fine tweezers! :)

Comment: @StarNamer -- these are strong enough that you can pry up the legs on one side a bit, bending the far legs a hair, then go back and deal with the other side.  You can mung your good fine tweezers doing this.